Ionic app transmits Advertising ID for children
My app is for both children and adults.
I am currently using AdMob in my app and recently received the following message from the Google Play Developer Console:
enter image description here
I'm using the following library for my ionic app: https://github.com/capacitor-community/adm
ob
I have already setup this parameter tagForChildDirectedTreatment
    await AdMob.initialize({
      tagForChildDirectedTreatment: true,
      tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,
    });


and I wonder hasn't it prevented the advertising ID being transmitted ?
Is there anything else I need to do ?
